# Why embedded PDF documents sometimes failed to load on my website

Tags: pdf

My WordPress site Reload on every hour, and sometimes some of the PDF documents (random) don't load. All embedded PDF's are only one sided. Why is this happening?

[image: PDF page]]

**UPDATE**: This happen only on Chrome browser, but I need to use that browser.

Comment: How are you embedding the PDFs - is there any processing done by WordPress, or are these just iframes with PDFs loaded directly into them? Is this actually a WordPress problem? (Doesn't feel like it to me.) Can you check the developer tools, specifically the network tab to make sure the documents loaded OK, and console tab to look for any errors?

Comment: I get STATUS code 304 in network but even if document are loaded correctly. Every time is the same status. I think that is maybe chrome viewer problem. I don't get that problem in other browser.